# R: count laps based on distance column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with information about a race and one column shows the distance that was driven by a car at a specific timepoint. It looks something like this:

```
data.frame(id = rep(c("A"), each = 15), 
           distance = seq(from = 1, to = 20, length.out = 15))

   id  distance 
1   A  1.000000   
2   A  2.357143   
3   A  3.714286   
4   A  5.071429   
5   A  6.428571   
6   A  7.785714   
7   A  9.142857   
8   A 10.500000   
9   A 11.857143   
10  A 13.214286   
11  A 14.571429   
12  A 15.928571   
13  A 17.285714   
14  A 18.642857   
15  A 20.000000
```

If I know that one lap is 5 units, I would like to create a new column that tells the lap at which each data point was taken, based on the distance driven. The result should look like this:

```
data.frame(id = rep("A", each = 15), 
           distance = seq(from = 1, to = 20, length.out = 15), 
           lap = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4))

   id  distance lap
1   A  1.000000   1
2   A  2.357143   1
3   A  3.714286   1
4   A  5.071429   2
5   A  6.428571   2
6   A  7.785714   2
7   A  9.142857   2
8   A 10.500000   3
9   A 11.857143   3
10  A 13.214286   3
11  A 14.571429   3
12  A 15.928571   4
13  A 17.285714   4
14  A 18.642857   4
15  A 20.000000   4
```

How can I do this, preferably using tidyverse?

Comment: what if you had a round value eg `5` should that be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an integer division problem. Just divide the distance by 5, and take the `ceiling`, which rounds it up to the nearest integer. This will give you the current lap number:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, lap = ceiling(distance/5))

   id  distance lap
1   A  1.000000   1
2   A  2.357143   1
3   A  3.714286   1
4   A  5.071429   2
5   A  6.428571   2
6   A  7.785714   2
7   A  9.142857   2
8   A 10.500000   3
9   A 11.857143   3
10  A 13.214286   3
11  A 14.571429   3
12  A 15.928571   4
13  A 17.285714   4
14  A 18.642857   4
15  A 20.000000   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `group_by()`, `case_when()` and `between()`.

Code:

```
df_desired = df %>% 
  group_by(id, distance,
  lap = case_when(between(distance, 1, 5)~"1",
                  between(distance, 5, 10)~ "2",
                  between(distance, 10, 15)~"3",
                  between(distance, 15, 20)~"4"))

# Desired output

# A tibble: 15 × 3
# Groups:   id, distance, lap [15]
   id    distance lap  
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
 1 A         1    1    
 2 A         2.36 1    
 3 A         3.71 1    
 4 A         5.07 2    
 5 A         6.43 2    
 6 A         7.79 2    
 7 A         9.14 2    
 8 A        10.5  3    
 9 A        11.9  3    
10 A        13.2  3    
11 A        14.6  3    
12 A        15.9  4    
13 A        17.3  4    
14 A        18.6  4    
15 A        20    4
```